# How to enable python snippets in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using the python extension that comes with vs code, "ms-python.python".

today, I don't know why my snippets is disabled. I don't know how to enable it.

Comment: you need to install jupyter extension too `code --install-extension ms-toolsai.jupyter` then the snippets will work

Comment: I have ms-toolsai.jupyter and it is enabled.

Comment: @g2m.agent -Do you mean that the "snippets" extension is disabled? Have you tried to open it in the VS Code extension bar and click "Enable"?

Answer (score 0):

i found this website, just install plugin. many options.
[https://marketplace.visualstudio.com](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=python&target=VSCode&category=Snippets&sortBy=Relevance)